# Keeping focus on cells in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating a spreadsheet that collects data from a site and inserts the data into excel.  For no reason other than a way for me to follow the data as it fills the sheet with information, is there a way to keep focus on the current cell to force the sheet to scroll (as if clicking the down arrow on the scroll bar) along with the data entry? My current code is as follows:

```
 else if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[7]/tbody  /tr/td[11]")).Count > 0)
            {
                 activesheet.Range["D" + n].Value = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[7]/tbody/tr/td[11]")).Text;                        
                 activesheet.Range["A" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                 activesheet.Range["B" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                 activesheet.Range["C" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                 activesheet.Range["D" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                 activesheet.Range["E" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
            }
```

I am sure it's very simple, I just have not been able to find this information/command, nor am I sure I am wording my searches correctly or if one even exists.

Comment: Not sure if you tried, but you can usually get the relevant property/method by recording a macro in normal Excel and inspecting the code it generates.  It is surprisingly thorough.  Often it will get you in the ballpark... or maybe the parking lot of the ballpark on some things. :)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.  I'll look into this as a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ScrollRow` property of the `ActiveWindow`.  If you just want to "hit the down arrow" you can increment.

```
//app is a valid reference to a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application instance
app.ActiveWindow.ScrollRow++;
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.window.scrollrow.aspx

Comment: There is also the `SmallScroll` method.  This is the one you will get if you record a macro in non-Interop Excel.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.window.smallscroll.aspx

Comment: These were very helpful!  I could not for the life of me figure out how to find these methods.  Thank you!! +1